# how to append multiple csv files from different folder in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have many csv files under different sub-directory in S3. 
I try to append all data with one csv file.

Is there any way to append all files using s3 or other AWS services?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the result csv is not very large (less than couple of Gb), you can use AWS Lambda to go through all subdirectories (keys) in S3 and write result file [for example into S3 again].

Also you can use AWS Glue for this operation, but I didn't use it.

In both cases you should write some script for joining files.